# .Netapplication logging

Tags: c#, logging

Is there a way to dynamically set On/Off specific log statements or log statements of specific types in .Net based applications? For instance, there are 100 log statements in my code and while my application is running in normal mode i want it to log only 10 messages. However, when running in diagnostic mode it must log all 100 messages.

Thanks for your time!

Xience

Comment: Every logging framework (including built in one) have ways to configure at least logging levels (error/warning). Each framework have different degrees of flexibility in configuration and different approaches to it. Consider looking through existing frameworks and trying to make more concrete question.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at log4net which is a fairly popular logging framework: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: +1 or NLog http://nlog-project.org/